# UPDATE AND REPLACE part or a string/record with parameter

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data, named-query

ALL>

I have here a named query to update and replace records.

`@NamedQuery(name = POST.UPDATE_POST_MESSAGE, query = "UPDATE Post p SET p.message = REPLACE(p.message, :value, 'ANONYMOUS')"`

I wanted the "old string" to be parameterized but it shows an error of

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of value that does not exist in the query string UPDATE Post p SET p.message = REPLACE(p.message, :value, 'ANONYMOUS').

here's the code in my dao layer:

```
private static final String VALUE = "value";

public void updateMessage(String value) {
  EntityManager entityManager = createEntityManager();

  entityManager.createNamedQuery(POST.UPDATE_POST_MESSAGE)
     .setParameter(VALUE, value)
     .executeUpdate();
}
```

I am not sure if we can use a parameter inside the replace function, been searching everywhere and i cant find an answer.
If not possible, can someone help/recommend a way to replace records using a parameter.

Comment: What is the value of the String VALUE - why not use a String literal `"value"` ?

Comment: depending on what is inputted by the user.

Comment: ??? `setParameter(VALUE, value)`  - The uppercase `VALUE` is referring to the name of the parameter

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i updated my question/code

Comment: I suggest that you give us the whole stacktrace **and** the value of `POST.UPDATE_POST_MESSAGE`

Answer (score 0):

Here you assigned parameter value to VALUE variable but using value((lower case ).